# NoUIslider - combining output values to create html

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I'm using 3 noUISliders. I want to combine the outputs of the 3 sliders to create an html output. Specifically, I want to use the combination to select an image file (ie. img135.jpg) where 1 is the output from the first slider, 3 is from the second and 5 is from the third. I have 27 images - I want to be able to select one based on the combined output of the 3 sliders ( 111.jpg, 211.jpg, 311.jpg, etc. through 555.jpg).

I have three sliders providing output:

```js
var slider1 = document.getElementById('slider1');

noUiSlider.create(slider1, {
  start: 1,
  connect: 'lower',
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  range: {
    'min': 1,
    'max': 5
  },
  snap: true,
  format: wNumb({
    decimals: 0
  })
});



var sliderOutput1 = document.getElementById('value-slider1');

slider1.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  sliderOutput1.innerHTML = values[handle];
});


var sliderOutput2 = document.getElementById('value-slider2');

slider2.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  sliderOutput2.innerHTML = values[handle];
});


var sliderOutput3 = document.getElementById('value-slider3');

slider3.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  sliderOutput3.innerHTML = values[handle];
});


var image_path = 'img' + sliderOutput1.val() + sliderOutput2.val() + sliderOutput3.val() + '.jpg';

("#img").html(image_path);
```

```html
<div id="slider1"></div>
<div id="slider2"></div>
<div id="slider3"></div>


<span id="value-slider1"> </span>
<span id="value-slider2"> </span>
<span id="value-slider3"> </span>

<div id="img"></div>
```

The sliders are all in and outputting values. I need advice on how to take the next step.
I'm pretty new at jscript, so any help or advice that you could provide would be great appreciated.

Ken

Comment: Here's the whole thing in jsFiddle.    [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kkottke/8th0fdw0/2/) http://jsfiddle.net/kkottke/8th0fdw0/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a lot fancier, but a simple pattern like the following should be fine:

```
function updatePicture() {
    var image_path = 'img' + sliderOutput1.val() + sliderOutput2.val() + sliderOutput3.val() + '.jpg';

    // I assume the missing $ was a typo
    $("#img").html(image_path);
}

slider1.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  sliderOutput1.innerHTML = values[handle];
  updatePicture();
});


var sliderOutput2 = document.getElementById('value-slider2');

slider2.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  sliderOutput2.innerHTML = values[handle];
  updatePicture();
});


var sliderOutput3 = document.getElementById('value-slider3');

slider3.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  sliderOutput3.innerHTML = values[handle];
  updatePicture();
});
```

Basically you get an event when any of the sliders change, you then proceed to update its output text (which you've done yourself), and the last step is to trigger the image refresh function which combines the three outputs into a usable path.

Interesting slider library by the way, I've never seen it before!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Not getting the result. I put everything into jsFiddle.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kkottke/8th0fdw0/2/) http://jsfiddle.net/kkottke/8th0fdw0/2/